# How do I bind XML Attributes to the action model in MVC Web API?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This may be a bug in the beta-release of the framework, or I'm doing something terribly wrong with my classes.

I've got a basic model I'm trying to receive via a POST to an action on my service. The model contains some properties as XML elements and some properties as XML attributes. The elements are bound to the model successfully, but the attributes are ignored.

A basic form of the model is:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Entry
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Link Parent { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

This serializes successfully to the following XML response.

```
<Entry Label="Test">
  <Parent Href="http://service/entries/123" />
  <Data>WibblyWobblyTimeyWimey</Data>
</Entry>
```

On sending a request back to the service with the same XML, I can see that only the Data element is persisted successfully.

Investigation into the `HttpActionContext` shows that the `RequestKeyValueModel` property only contains keys "Data" and "Parent", and that only "Data" has a value.

I've tested deserialization of the entry manually and can successfully deserialize the response using a simple test client powered by the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to read the request as an object (and exercise the `MediaTypeFormatter` in the process).

Is there some trick I've missed, some setting somewhere like which I've overlooked? I'm convinced the problem lies in the `IActionBinder` attempting to bind the values from the deserialized XML request to the arguments on the action, but I don't have any more information as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that this is a problem with the current model binding implemented by the Beta release of the framework (and subsequently improved since).

[This article suggested the work-around is to disable model binding in favour of a simpler "serialization" model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/27/disabling-model-binding-on-asp-net-web-apis-beta.aspx), which sounded closer to what I actually wanted.

Unfortunately, as a side-effect, this dropped out *all* of the route parameter binding too, so I was no longer getting any of the parameters from the URL and the action would not execute without the missing values.

However, I managed to work around that problem by introducing the following attribute:

```
public class AddRouteParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var descriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor
            as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
        var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

        foreach (var key in actionContext.ActionArguments.Keys.ToList())
        {
            if (actionContext.ActionArguments[key] == null)
            {
                var parameter = parameters
                    .SingleOrDefault(param => param.Name == key);

                var valueProvider = new RouteDataValueProvider(
                    actionContext,
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var result = valueProvider.GetValue(key);

                if (result != null && parameter != null)
                {
                    actionContext.ActionArguments[key]
                        = result.ConvertTo(parameter.ParameterType);
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

It's a bit crufty (as all the best workarounds should be), but it uses the existing `RouteDataValueProvider` class to read the route information in as the correct type whenever a parameter is not populated by the normal deserialization process. I'm sure there are cases that it doesn't work with, but so far it has filled the gap I needed filling and resolves the issue for me without having to plumb *really* deep into the framework.

Hopefully, if you have a similar problem, you can refer to this code until the RC, at which point we're assured these problems go away.